# Is it possible to post coverage for multiple packages to Coveralls?

Tags: go, coveralls

I want to track test coverage on a go project using Coveralls, the instructions for the integration reference using 
https://github.com/mattn/goveralls

```
cd $GOPATH/src/github.com/yourusername/yourpackage
$ goveralls your_repos_coveralls_token
```

However, this only posts the results for one package and running for packages in turn does not work as the final run overwrites all other runs. Has anyone figured out how to get coverage for multiple packages?

Comment: Since Feb. 2018 and Go 1.10, it is possible: see [my answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47232544/6309).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I ended up using this [script](https://github.com/gopns/gopns/blob/master/test-coverage.sh):

```bash
echo "mode: set" > acc.out
for Dir in $(find ./* -maxdepth 10 -type d );
do
        if ls $Dir/*.go &> /dev/null;
        then
            go test -coverprofile=profile.out $Dir
            if [ -f profile.out ]
            then
                cat profile.out | grep -v "mode: set" >> acc.out
            fi
fi
done
goveralls -coverprofile=acc.out $COVERALLS
rm -rf ./profile.out
rm -rf ./acc.out
```

It basically finds all the directories in the path and prints a coverage profile for them separately. It then concatenates the files into one big profile and ships them off to coveralls.

Answer (score 5):

Taking Usman's answer, and altering it to support skipping Godep and other irrelevant folders:

```bash
echo "mode: set" > acc.out
for Dir in $(go list ./...); 
do
    returnval=`go test -coverprofile=profile.out $Dir`
    echo ${returnval}
    if [[ ${returnval} != *FAIL* ]]
    then
        if [ -f profile.out ]
        then
            cat profile.out | grep -v "mode: set" >> acc.out 
        fi
    else
        exit 1
    fi  

done
if [ -n "$COVERALLS_TOKEN" ]
then
    goveralls -coverprofile=acc.out -repotoken=$COVERALLS_TOKEN -service=travis-pro
fi  

rm -rf ./profile.out
rm -rf ./acc.out
```

Notice that instead of looking at every directory, I us the `go list ./...` command which lists all directories that actually get used to build the go package.

Hope that helps others.

** EDIT **

If you are using the `vendor` folder for Go v.1.6+ then this script filters out the dependencies:

```bash
echo "mode: set" > acc.out
for Dir in $(go list ./...); 
do
    if [[ ${Dir} != *"/vendor/"* ]]
    then
        returnval=`go test -coverprofile=profile.out $Dir`
        echo ${returnval}
        if [[ ${returnval} != *FAIL* ]]
        then
            if [ -f profile.out ]
            then
                cat profile.out | grep -v "mode: set" >> acc.out 
            fi
        else
            exit 1
        fi
    else
        exit 1
    fi  

done
if [ -n "$COVERALLS_TOKEN" ]
then
    goveralls -coverprofile=acc.out -repotoken=$COVERALLS_TOKEN -service=travis-pro
fi
```

Answer (score 4):

> Has anyone figured out how to get coverage for multiple packages?

Note: with Go 1.10 (Q1 2018), that... will actually be possible.
See [CL 76875](https://go-review.googlesource.com/c/go/+/76875)

> ### `cmd/go`: allow `-coverprofile` with multiple packages being tested

You can see the implementation of a multiple package code coverage test in [commit 283558e](https://go.googlesource.com/go/+/283558e42b88a6afa39da6ad4ae87558dc053776%5E%21/#F1)

---

[Jeff Martin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13100/jeff-martin) has since the [release of Go 1.10](https://golang.org/doc/devel/release.html#go1.10) (Feb. 2018) confirmed [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21126011/is-it-possible-to-post-coverage-for-multiple-packages-to-coveralls/47232544?noredirect=1#comment87566721_47232544):

- `go test -v -cover ./pkgA/... ./pkgB/... -coverprofile=cover.out` gets a good profile and
- `go tool cover -func "cover.out"` will get a `total: (statements) 52.5%`.

So it is working!

Comment: i can confirm that something similar to `go test -v -cover ./pkgA/... ./pkgB/... -coverprofile=cover.out`  gets a good profile and 
`go tool cover -func "cover.out"` will get a total:
`total:                                                                                  (statements)            52.5%`

Comment: @JeffMartin Thank you! I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Answer (score 2):

I have been using http://github.com/axw/gocov to get my code coverage.

I trigger this in a bash script, in here I call all my packages.

I also use http://github.com/matm/gocov-html to format into html.

```
 coverage)
       echo "Testing Code Coverage"
       cd "${SERVERPATH}/package1/pack"
       GOPATH=${GOPATH} gocov test ./... > coverage.json 
       GOPATH=${GOPATH} gocov-html coverage.json > coverage_report.html

       cd "${SERVERPATH}/package2/pack"
       GOPATH=${GOPATH} gocov test ./... > coverage.json 
       GOPATH=${GOPATH} gocov-html coverage.json > coverage_report.html
     ;;
```

Hope that helps a little bit.

Comment: I ended up using something very similar, see my answer

Answer (score 1):

Here is a pure GO solution:

I create a library that may help, https://github.com/bluesuncorp/overalls

all it does is recursively go through each directory ( aka each package ), run go test and produce coverprofiles, then merges all profiles into a single one at the root of the project directory called overalls.coverprofile

then you can use a tool like https://github.com/mattn/goveralls to send it to coveralls.io

hope everyone likes

Answer (score 1):

In Go 1.13, following command generates coverage for multiple packages

```
go test -v -coverpkg=./... -coverprofile=profile.cov ./...
go tool cover -func profile.cov
```

for html report

```
go tool cover -html=profile.cov -o cover.html
```